# How to check compactness of linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let the continuous linear operator $T:l^2\to l^2$ be defined by

$$T(x_1,x_2...)=(0,x_1,0,x_3,0,x_5,0...).$$

Are $T$ and $T^2$ compact?

A linear operator $T: X\to Y$ is said to be compact if image of any bounded subset of X is relatively compact(closure is compact) in Y,where X and Y are normed(Banach) spaces.

But I can't understand how to use it? does  there exist any simple  method ?Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: $T$ is not compact. Try to find a sequence $e_i$ so that $\|e_i\|=1$ but $Te_i$ does not converges.

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $(e_n)$ the canonical orthonormal basis of $\ell^2$, that is, $(e_n)_i=\delta_{ni}$. Then $B:=\{e_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ is a bounded subset of $\ell^2$ and $T(B)=\{0\}\cup\{e_{2n}\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$. The sequence $(e_{2n})$ has no Cauchy-subsequence: $\|e_{2n}-e_{2m}\|^2=2$ for any $m,n\in\mathbb N$. Thus, $T(B)$ cannot be relatively compact.

On the other hand, $T^2=0$, and $0$ is obviously a compact operator.