# Compactness/non-compactness of a linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

I was fretting over this particular question which I found answered in the following link : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1628972/817522 However now I have this notion that any sequence $T(x_n)$ will have the convergent 0(zero) subsequence. Then by characterization of compact operators should T be compact?

Comment: Can ypu state precisely your conditions? What is $x_n$?

Comment: $x_n$ has been taken to be any bounded sequence. And for that particular answer in the link,it is the orthonormal basis.